# setting default design and font in powerpoint 2016

Tags: powerpoint

This question may be a bit too simplistic for this community but I'm stumped. When preparing a lecture I prefer to have a black background with white text on a square slide.

I know how to create a theme to get the slide design quickly.
I know how to change font text color.

But...

**1) How do I assign a theme to default (instead of having to load it manually each time)?**

**2) How do I change the default text color?**

Ideally, I'd like to have powerpoint open with my custom theme and having white text as the default color so I don't need to change these settings manually.

much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point Google here to get a more detailed set of instrux,

https://www.google.com/search?q=default+theme+powerpoint+2016&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

But basically you rightclick the theme you want to set as default in the Themes gallery, then choose Set as Default.

When creating your theme, add a text box, format it to the font style you want, then right click and choose Set as Default Text Box.  This will set the font style for any newly added text.  Also make sure that the font theme included in your theme specifies the fonts you want for title and body text. To do this, go to View | Slide Master. On the Slide Master tab, you can use the Fonts button in the Background group to choose or modify the font theme.